# "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed" - even with a using(context) statement and ToList()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I have an MVC3 Project running with EF Code First.

Here is my code for Home/Index:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var IndVM = new IndexVM();
    using (QuoteContext QDomain = new QuoteContext())
    {
        IndVM.Quotes = QDomain.Quotes.Include("Tags").Include("Author").OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).Take(5).ToList();
        IndVM.Tags = QDomain.Tags.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quotes.Count).ToList();
        IndVM.Authors = QDomain.Authors.OrderByDescending(x => x.Quotes.Count).Take(5).ToList();
    }
    return View(IndVM);
}
```

As you can see I have the Querying stuff inside a using statement, and I am also calling the `ToList()`, but I still get the error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Is this a bug in EF Code First?

Comment: Show us where exactly you get the error.

Comment: Hello Eranga. Here is a [screenshot](http://i40.tinypic.com/14mf5w8.jpg) of the error page. :(

Comment: @Ciwan: The context shouldn't be disposed on that line.  Maybe the source has gotten out of sync with the code on the server.  Can you try doing a full rebuild and trying for that screenshot again?

Comment: Hi Merlyn. I just did, I stopped the server instance (taskbar), I did 3 cleans of the solution, then rebuilt the whole thing, and run it, and got exact same error, on exact same line. Could I have messed my entity class definitions ? link at the bottom (my other post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off lazy loading, otherwise the serializer will try to traverse navigation properties and throw this exception.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var IndVM = new IndexVM();
    using (QuoteContext QDomain = new QuoteContext())
    {
        QDomain.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        // Query and populate IndVM here...
    }
    return View(IndVM);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Merlyn. Where do I put that code ? Sorry still learning.

Comment: @Ciwan: Filled out a little more.  Off-topic: I recommend you use `initialCase` style for local variables, and reserve capitalized names only for namespaces, classes, properties, and methods.

Comment: Thanks Merlyn. From my understanding, it would mean it has to go after the defining of QDomain, thus inside the using statement (cause QDomain doesn't exists prior to that). So I went and did that, although there was no ContextOptions, there was this [ QDomain.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; ] ... but still I get the exact same error. :(

Comment: @Ciwan: Hmm, I thought I remembered that working...  Well, how about trying: `QDomain.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Comment: Hi Merlyn. I got same error again. I might messed up something on my Entity classes, here is a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/8iBF01Wz) of them. I've been Google searching on this for a day and a half now, and still can't figure it out. :(

Comment: @Ciwan: Got to go to bed now, but will pick this up tomorrow if you don't have a better answer.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue, and you won't believe it. All I did was move the troublesom line above the others, [like so](http://pastebin.com/G4vhZvue) Please note that my code was working before, but only after a Refresh. So when I run my application first time, it would give the ObjectDisposed error, but if I refreshed it would work. No however that I've moved things about, it all seems fine and runs perfectly from the first go. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Ciwan: Glad it got sorted out.  That's ... strange.  So essentially you did nothing and it got solved? :)